# dbt-mysql - old version?

Tags: pip, dbt, dbt-mysql

I installed dbt-postgres and dbt-mysql with pip:

`pip install dbt-postgres`
`pip install dbt-mysql`

On the dbt-mysql package, pip printed this error:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
dbt-postgres 1.5.3 requires dbt-core==1.5.3, but you have dbt-core 0.19.2 which is incompatible.
```

I'm using venv with Python 3.10.6, pip 22.0.2.

According to https://pypi.org/project/dbt-mysql/#description the latest version is 1.1.0, I don't know why it got 0.19.2.

Now dbt is broken, all dbt commands including `dbt --version` fail with `NotImplementedError`.

Comment: Did you try simply pip installing/upgrading dbt-core?

Comment: Yes, I tried `pip install "dbt-core==1.5.3"` (same result) and `pip install "dbt-mysql==1.1.0"`(not found).

Comment: OK, according to https://github.com/dbeatty10/dbt-mysql#dbt-mysql it is an experimental plugin and Python 3.10 is not supported :-/

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/dbeatty10/dbt-mysql#dbt-mysql it is an experimental plugin and Python 3.10 is not supported at the moment. There are several issues related to compatibility with latest dbt versions and newer Python.

I installed Python 3.9:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt install python3.9
sudo apt-get install python3.9-venv
python3.9 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install dbt-mysql
pip install "dbt-postgres==1.1.0"
```

It installs an outdated version of dbt but at least it seems to work.